# How to properly construct a Twitter Future

Tags: multithreading, scala, twitter, future

We're using Finatra and have services return a Twitter `Future`.
Currently we use either `Future { ... }` or `Future.value(..)` to construct `Future` instances, but looking at the source this does not seem correct.

In `Future.apply` source doc it says: "that `a` is executed in the calling thread and as such some care must be taken with blocking code."

So, how to create a `Future` which executes the function on a separate thread, just like the Scala `Future` does?

Comment: I would recommend creating an issue [here](https://github.com/twitter/util/issues)

Comment: @thefoureye what "issue"?

Comment: Agree with @Dima. It's no issue just badly documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `FuturePool` for that. Something like `val future = FuturePool.defaultPool { doStuff () }`

Both `Future.value` and `Future.apply` are immediate. They are more or less equivalent to `scala.concurrent.Future.successful`.

Comment: Thanks. I now also found this: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html#DontBlock saying the same thing. Too bad this is not properly documented in the Finagle documentation.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to Dima's answer, but...

Doing things in a background thread (FuturePool) because your server is struggling to keep up with request load isn't usually the correct solution.  Assuming you are just processing a CPU intensive task for 100ms, its probably better to keep it on the same thread and adjust the number of servers you have and the number of threads servicing requests.

But if you are doing something like querying a database or remote service, that call would ideally return a truly asynchronous Future that isn't blocking any finagle threads.

If you have a sync API wrapping a network service, then FuturePool is probably the correct thing to workaround it.

Comment: We're doing db and external services calls so that's why stuff has to run async so resources on this services are freed so it can continue handling next requests while 'waiting' for a response from external systems.

Comment: In an ideal world you would use a finagle client to talk to the db and those external services and you wouldn't need a FuturePool. If that is not an option then it sounds like you are doing the right thing.

Comment: @YuriSchimke do you know of a finagle client implementation capable of talking to a database (and/or cassandra/dynamo/S3)? I am not aware of any ...

Comment: Depends on your database eg MySQL http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/Protocols.html